# Use ScheduledExecutorService schedule to schedule a task from a spawned thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, timertask, scheduledexecutorservice

I am planning on implementing a timer service for my java application. 
The core structure is like so.

In the Base class, I call scheduleATassk() to start the first task with delay set. When the delay is up, it will call onTimeUp() to notify me that we can calculate the next alarm duration. So in onTimeUp(), if the conditions are met, i will call scheduleATassk() with the new duration and the cycles repeats.

My question is:
The very first task will be scheduled by the main thread (notice in the Base class's constructor (the main thread), it calls scheduleATassk() to get the alarm running). However, any subsequent scheduleATassk() will be call by the child thread. Are there any effect? Is it safe? Can I improve on the design?

```
public class Base {

    private ScheduledExecutorService service = null;

    public Base() {
         service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
         scheduleATassk(10);
    }

    public void onTimeUp() throws Exception {
        if (hasMoreTime) {
            scheduleATassk(newCalculatedDuration);
       } else {
          System.out.println("TIMER IS UP");
       }
    }

    protected void scheduleATassk(long duration) {
            service.schedule(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                             onTimeUp();
                        }
                    }, duration, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);}
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand I can do scheduleAtFixRate, but I need to be able to dynamically change the timer duration based on the previous run results.